# I am getting a union type string | number on an object that suppose to have only strings?

Tags: typescript

I have the following state logic the issue is that for some reason I am getting a union type string and a number on the Object Key but it has to  show only strings.

```js
// State
const inicialState: {
  [key: string]: string;
  type: 'a' |'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' | 'f' | 'g'
  } = {
  names: '',
  data: '',
  type: 'a',
};

const [selected, setSelected] = useState < typeof inicialState > (inicialState);


type ObjectKey = keyof typeof selected;

// type ObjectKey = string | number ??
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that keyof can be both a number or a string [TS Document](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html)
I removed the `keyof` keyword and the `ObjectKey` has type of inicialState, though you mark the key in that state as a string. I figure that making that a number would be more beneficial.